# Smart pointers usage

Tags: c++, pointers, boost, smart-pointers

I have a project and I want make smart pointers usage better.

The main idea is to use them when returning new object from function. The question is what smart pointer to use? **auto_ptr** or **shared_ptr** from boost? As I know, auto_ptr is slower but it can fall back to the 'pure' pointer.

And if I'll use smart pointer in place where I don't need it, would it make the perfomance slower?

Comment: Don't choose smart pointers based on perceived efficiency (for one humans are absolutely terrible at perceiving efficiency and as demonstrated usually get it wrong). Choose the smart pointer that demonstrates how you expect the pointer to be used. If you are transferring ownership auto_ptr is good, if you are creating an implicitly shared object then shared_ptr is better.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What makes you think `auto_ptr` is slower than `shared_ptr`? Typically I would expect the reverse to be true, since `shared_ptr` needs to update the reference count.

As for which you should use, different smart pointers imply different ownership semantics. Ownership implies the responsibility to delete the object when it is no longer needed.

- A raw pointer implies **no ownership**; a program that uses smart pointers correctly may still make use of raw pointers in a lot of places where ownership is not intended (for example, if you need to pass an optional reference to an object into a function, you would often use a raw pointer).
- `scoped_ptr` implies **single** (ie, non-shared), **non-transferable** ownership.
- `auto_ptr` implies **single** (ie, non-shared) **transferable** ownership. This is the smart pointer I would use to return a newly constructed object from a function (the function is *transferring* the object to its caller). `auto_ptr` suffers from the disadvantage that due to limitations of the language when `auto_ptr` was defined, it is difficult to use correctly (this has given it a very bad reputation, though the intended purpose of a smart pointer with single, transferable ownership semantics was and is both valid and useful).
- `unique_ptr` has the same semantics as `auto_ptr`, but uses new C++0x features (rvalue references) to make it a lot safer (less prone to incorrect use) than `auto_ptr`. If you are developing on a platform where `unique_ptr` is available, then you should use it instead of `auto_ptr`.
- `shared_ptr` implies **shared** ownership. In my opinion this is over-used. It does have many valid uses, but it should *not* simply be used as a default option.

I would also add that `shared_ptr` is often used with STL containers because the other smart pointer classes do not achieve their intended function in that context (due to copying of values internally within the container). This often leads to use of `shared_ptr` where shared ownership is not really the intended meaning. In these cases, I suggest (where possible) using the boost pointer-container classes (`ptr_vector`, `ptr_map` and so on), which provide the (commonly desired) semantics of a container with transferable, but single (non-shared) ownership.

You should always think about the ownership of your objects: in most cases, with a clean system design, each object has one obvious owner, and ownership does not need to be shared. This has the advantage that it is easy to see exactly where and when objects will be freed, and no reference counting overhead is needed.

[edited to note the new `unique_ptr`]

Comment: Anyway there are still some clean scenarios where shared_ptr is useful. I have a threading-framework where the thread-information is stored in a shared_ptr one copy is given to the thread object itself and released when the threads ends another copy is given to the caller. This is the cleanest way to ensure clean-up after a thread ends but allows a caller to safely track the current state of the thread.

Comment: Possibly "in most cases, with a clean system design" was too strong. True shared ownership situations aren't *that* rare (though far less common than single ownership). Thanks for providing a good example.

Answer (score 2):

You probably should use `shared_ptr<>`. It's hard to be more specific without knowing what exactly you want to do. Best read its [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm) and see if it does what you need.

The performance difference will most likely be negligible. Only in extreme cases there might me an noticeable impact, like when copying these pointers many million times each second.

Comment: The performance difference will NOT be negligible. Since the overhead of shared_ptr is not only the incrementing and decrementing of the reference counter. There is also a second new/delete per object for the maintenance information! And since heap is slow this may be bad in some situations. Additionally shared_ptr may lead to memory leaks if you have circular references (Which may be solved by using weak_ptr; But you have to think a lot more!).

Comment: @rstevens: You can use `make_shared()` which does only one allocation. Anyway, typically performance bottlenecks aren't in the pointers used, and I suspect the OPs concern is premature optimization. Also you have to think about memory leaks no matter what kind of smart pointer or non-smart pointer you use. If anything, `shared_ptr`/`weak_ptr` makes it easier to handle.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer shared_ptr, auto_ptr can cause a lot of trouble and its use is not too intuitive. If you expect this object to be inserted on a STL container, so you certainly want to use shared_ptr.

Abot the performance you have a cost, but this is minimal and you can ignore it most of the time.

Comment: Performance cost can be quite high! Be sure to profile after using smart ptrs to see if the impact is acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

Depends.
Shared pointers have a better use than auto_ptr which have the unusual characteristic of changing ownership on assignments.
Also auto_ptr can not be used in containers.
Also you can not use auto_ptr as return values if you do not want to transfer ownership.
Shared pointers have all the benefits of smart pointers, have overloaded the relevant operators to act like a pointer and can be used in containers.
Having said that, they are not cheap to use.
You must analyze your needs to decide if you actually gain something by avoiding the shared_pointer implementation overheads

Comment: Wrong: auto_ptr can be used in containers...because of it's crude characteristic... (Usage in containers is the reason for those characteristics!!!)

Comment: @rstevens:I have no idea what your comment means.`auto_ptr` does NOT meet one of the most fundamental requirements for elements in standard containers.After a copy or assignment  of an `auto_ptr` source and sink are not equivalent.So `auto_ptr` should NOT be used in standard containers.

Comment: @user384706: auto_ptr is built to be usable in standard containers like std::vector and std::list. It may cause problems in other containers but as std::auto_ptr and std::-Containers are developped together they are guaranteed to work together.

Comment: @rstevens:Containers of `auto_ptrs` are prohibited (as per standard comitee mandate).Code attempted to use them should not compile.However there are STL implementation that (erroneously) do not reject this case.Just because `auto_ptr`s are part of the standard library does not mean they work ok with stl containers. That's plain wrong!!

Answer (score 0):

Use only shared_ptr. With auto_ptr you can have ONLY ONE reference to your object. Also auto_ptr isn't slower it must work faster than shared_ptr.

To not ask such questions you need to know, how this smart pointers work.

auto_ptr just storing pointer to your object and destroying it in it's destructor.

The problem of auto_ptr is that when you are trying to copy it it's stopping to point to your object.

For example

auto_ptr a_ptr(new someClass);

auto_ptr  another_ptr=aptr;// after this another_ptr is pointing to your class, but a_ptr isn't pointing to it anymore!

This is why I don't recomend you to use auto_ptr.

Shared pointer counting how much smart pointers are pointing to your object and destroying your object when there is no more pointers to it. That's why you can have more than 1 pointer pointing to your object.

But Shared pointer also isn't perfect. And if in your program you have cyclic graph (when you have classes A and B and A have a member shared_ptr wich points to B and B have or B's member objects have shared_ptr pointing to A) than A and B will never deleted and you will have memory lick.

To write correct code with shared_ptr you need to be careful and also use weak_ptr.
For more information look at here http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/smart_ptr/smart_ptr.htm